# quicktime mute all files droplet

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, quicktime

Want an applescript droplet that opens files in QuickTime and mutes them all. The script only mutes the front most opened file.

```
on open the_Droppings
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to activate
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to open the_Droppings
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player 7"
        keystroke (ASCII character 31) using {command down, option down}
    end tell
end open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I got it to work.

```
on open the_Droppings
    activate application "QuickTime Player 7"
    repeat with oneDrop in the_Droppings
        tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
            open oneDrop
            set sound volume of document 1 to 0
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell each window open in Quicktime in turn to perform the action. An action has to have a specific target in Applescript; they way you have it written now, you are tell the Quicktime application, not a window in Quicktime.

Untested:

```
on open the_Droppings
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7" to activate
    tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
        open the_Droppings
        set documentCount to (count documents)
    end tell
    repeat with thisDocument from 1 to documentCount
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "QuickTime Player 7"
                tell document thisDocument
                    keystroke (ASCII character 31) using {command down, option down}
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

But I believe there is also a preference to not have movies auto-play upon opening as well.

Comment: I understand what you are saying just don't know how to target all the windows.

Comment: telling the process may not recognize a document pointed towards via the script. I wouldn't know of another way to do this, and sometimes I come across those odd things that just can't be done. It happens.

Comment: that is what I was thinking. Thanks for trying.